# com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket on Heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku, spring-boot

I have a deployed Springboot server on heroku that runs like its supposed to except mlab will not create a connection. The weird thing is that it worked one time, but I had to restart the server, and it never connected again. I recreated the issue locally by trying to start the server without starting mongodb. The error I get is

```
2017-05-24T13:10:56.522858+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-05-24T13:10:56.522859+00:00 app[web.1]: com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
2017-05-24T13:10:56.522860+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
2017-05-24T13:10:56.522861+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
2017-05-24T13:10:56.522862+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
2017-05-24T13:10:56.522863+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-05-24T13:10:56.522863+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2017-05-24T13:10:56.522865+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-05-24T13:10:56.522865+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-05-24T13:10:56.522866+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-05-24T13:10:56.522867+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-05-24T13:10:56.522867+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-05-24T13:10:56.522868+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-05-24T13:10:56.522869+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
2017-05-24T13:10:56.522869+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
2017-05-24T13:10:56.522871+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

I am using spring.data.mongodb.uri=${MONGODB_URI} to pull the mongo uri, but I am having no luck at all. I've been trying to get this to connect for two days not with only one successful connection for some weird reason. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also notices this in the heroku logs

Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

Comment: Anguilar  it clearly shows that Mongo_db_uri you are provided is either incorrect or it's not running , request u to share the file in which you have defined the mongo_db_uri